# How to retrieve a branch after finishing a branch in gitflow

Tags: git, git-flow

I know that when you start for example a feature branch, you type git flow feature start  [] and if you want to finish a branch, you type git flow feature finish .

But when you finish a branch, it merges it with develop and deletes the branch automatically.. How do i retrieve that branch?

Comment: like you said it deletes the branch, so how can one retrieve it, doesnt it ? May be if you still need your branch ; you would have to dont enter git flow .. finish ?

Comment: Why do you need to retrieve the branch?

Answer (score 2):

If you just did that, the feature would be second parent of the current commit (the merge commit). You can recreate the branch with

```
 git branch my-feature HEAD^2
```

to create it and check it out in one go

```
 git checkout -b my-feature HEAD^2
```

If it's been a while, it's probably not the second parent of the current commit. Use

```
 gitk
```

or

```
git log --graph --oneline
```

to find where that branch finished and use the HASH or tree-ish to recreat it. If you guarantee that the merge message is the default one, you can

```
git branch my-feature $(git log -1 --format=%H --grep="merge branch 'my-feature'")^2
```

Answer (score 1):

In git branches are really just pointers to commits.  Although you can not "retrieve" a branch after it's deleted, you can make a new branch pointing to the same commit as the deleted branch.

One way would be to get the SHA1 of that commit with `gitk --all`.  Then you just execute

```
 git checkout -b [branch name] [sha1 of your commit]
```

Comment: the reflog will not necessarily have the last commit of the feature just before the merge. This carries assumptions that they were using gitflow exclusively and were working on that feature before issuing the branch finish command.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to undo the branch merge.

Here that a look at the accepted anwser => [CLICK ME!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450039/how-to-undo-git-flow-feature-finish/13505455#13505455)

These steps should do the trick:

Get the sha's needed:

```
git log
```

`<sha1>` is the commit right before the merge
`<sha2>` is the last commit on develop before you started working on the feature

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b feature/<feature-name>
git reset <sha1> --hard
git checkout develop
git reset <sha2> --hard
```

Push your feature branch.

Comment: -1 this answer is simply not accurate, and the advice given destructive (git reset hard on develop?). Moreover the linked question  asks something quite different - the answer given does not apply here.