# How to undo git flow feature finish?

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-flow

I am learning git-flow and I just did `git flow feature finish <feature-name>`, which merged my feature branch to develop and removed it.

Instead of this, I want to push the feature branch to github, so I can merge it after a peer review.

So the question is, how do I 'undo' this command. Or in other words , how can I move my last two commits from develop to my feature branch?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

These steps should do the trick:

Get the sha's needed:

```
git log
```

`<sha1>` is the commit right before the merge
`<sha2>` is the last commit on develop before you started working on the feature

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b feature/<feature-name>
git reset <sha1> --hard
git checkout develop
git reset <sha2> --hard
```

Push your feature branch.

Comment: I had to read this few times before I realized why reset on the feature branch (third line). Looks obvious in hidsight :) Thanks! (btw the `<sha's>` get lost in the markup)

Comment: If `git flow feature finish` was your last action, you can just do `git reset --hard HEAD^` in both branches instead of using commit's shas, as the commits would be the lasts in boths cases.

Comment: And if like me, you're trying to undo a `hotfix finish`, you also need to reset the last commit in the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easiest to just update master (we call it default) [back to origin](https://superuser.com/questions/273172/how-do-i-reset-master-to-origin-master), with either

```
git checkout -B master origin/master
```

or the equivalent newer command

```
git switch -C master origin/master
```

checkout -B and switch -C (or --force-create) both move the branch to the new location if it already exists.

**Update** After thinking about it later, I half-considered deleting this, though it worked for me, because I suspect it might only work for the fast-forward case, rather than a regular merge.  That also might explain why `git reset --hard <SHA-from-reflog>` didn't work for me and got me into a confused state, i.e., because I "reset" my local `master` rather than the feature branch head.