# Git-Flow undo a finished feature branch

Tags: git, git-flow

What options do you have if you want to "undo" a feature branch? Let's say you add a new feature `supercool-feature` which you finish (merge into development and delete the feature branch) and then it goes into a release. But then your users really dislike this `supercool-feature`. How can I undo/rewind/reverse this feature which has been already merged into development and a release?

I'm using SourceTree to do my versioning.

Comment: Well you revert the merge... Obviously its a little more complex than that but the detail lies in how your organise your code and your tests etc.  I've a feeling there's more to this question.

Comment: Also this is not really a git-flow specific question. What git-flow has done for you is just create your feature branch from develop and then merge it back into develop. There is no magic stuff going on in git-flow, it's all just git.

Comment: @AlexBrown so how do I revert the merge? I'm not sure if you are familiar with how the git-flow process works. But when you finish a feature in git-flow it is merged into a "development" branch and then the feature branch is deleted. When you decide to make a release, you make a new branch from development and you make your release-specific changes and then merge this into "master". So how would I revert the `supercool-feature` that was merged into development?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't identified git-flow as a product - you are right I'm not familiar with it.  However, in base git, the merge point of the feature branch should be a commit itself - simply find it and revert it.

Comment: Use [`git revert`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6217372/1615903). It fits the git-flow process best.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to undo git flow feature finish?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450039/how-to-undo-git-flow-feature-finish)

Comment: @Hasturkun No, not a duplicate. In that other question, the merge commit was done locally but not pushed anywhere, and that's an important enough difference that the answers are completely different.

Comment: @hvd: Okay. I mostly marked since I removed Peter van der Does' comment about being duplicates. (since that didn't belong in the question)

Comment: @Hasturkun Ah, thanks for the explanation, I hadn't seen that. Agreed, that shouldn't have been put in the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Run this command**

```
git revert -m 1 <sha1 of M>
```

**Explanation**

Your situation is about as follows:

> ```
> A-B-----C---D-M     # master
>    \         /
>     X-Y---Z-        # supercool-feature
> ```

A, B, C and D were in your master branch, X, Y and Z in your feature branch. When you did `git merge supercool-feature` Git created a "merge commit" M for you. This commit encloses all commits from your feature branch as well as possible fixes to fix merge conflicts. So if you `revert` that one commit, every change from your featurebranch will be gone again.

Comment: devils advocate: how does it know to remove everything from supercool feature  XZY, and not everything from master (CD)? the merge is symmetric...

Comment: Merges are not symmetric. `git merge` looks at the changeset from the branch to be merged (`git diff B..Z`) and squashes it into one commit.

Comment: after reverting the merge commit, what if we need that feature again in future? The feature branch has already been deleted and the merge commit reverted, wouldn't all the code related to feature be lost ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 You could always create a branch at the tip of that "reverted" feature branch. E.g. `git branch feature/my-reverted-feature {sha}`. Since it's now "referenced", you'll have access to the branch's history and it won't be cleaned up by Git.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the command is

```
git revert -m 1 <sha1 of M>
```

which remove M moving back on branch containing X,Y,Z which is not the mainline 1.

Comment: Hey fella, did you copy paste from the answer above you?